# Why doesn't heap memory used go down after a GC in CLR?

Tags: asp.net, garbage-collection, heap-memory, coreclr

I wrote a test program to explore the how does GC works in ASP.NET Core.

The program ran in docker with memory limits set below 9mb.

I found that the program will be killed by docker because of it used out of memory that docker limited.

I thought that the GC didn't be triggered. But when I recorded the GC information in program,I found that it occurs too many times while the heap memory didn't go down. Why ?

The version of ASP.NET Core is 2.2 . I have already tried the latest version 3.0-preview5, It works fine. I think the optimize of GC in .NET Core 3.0 make the different consequence. But I can not figure out why.

Here is some informations about GC optimize in Core3.0.

PR: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/22180/files

Blog: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/running-with-server-gc-in-a-small-container-scenario-part-1-hard-limit-for-the-gc-heap/

My code is below:

```
            if (GCSettings.IsServerGC == true)
                    Console.WriteLine("Server GC");
            else
                    Console.WriteLine("GC WorkStationGC");
            byte[] buffer;
            for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                buffer = new byte[ 1024 * 1024];


                Console.WriteLine($"allocate number {i+1} objet ");

                var num = GC.CollectionCount(0);
                var usedMemory = GC.GetTotalMemory(false) /1024 /1024;

                Console.WriteLine($"heap use {usedMemory} mb");
                Console.WriteLine($"GC occurs {num} times");
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
           }
```

docker run command:

```
docker run -m 9mb -t xxx
```

the result with .NET Core2.2 :

```
GC WorkStationGC
allocate number 1 objet 
heap use 1 mb
GC occurs 0 times
allocate number 2 objet 
heap use 2 mb
GC occurs 0 times
allocate number 3 objet 
heap use 3 mb
GC occurs 0 times
allocate number 4 objet 
heap use 1 mb
GC occurs 1 times
allocate number 5 objet 
heap use 2 mb
GC occurs 1 times
allocate number 6 objet 
heap use 3 mb
GC occurs 1 times
allocate number 7 objet 
heap use 4 mb
GC occurs 2 times
allocate number 8 objet 
heap use 5 mb
GC occurs 3 times
allocate number 9 objet 
heap use 6 mb
GC occurs 4 times
allocate number 10 objet 
heap use 7 mb
GC occurs 5 times
allocate number 11 objet 
heap use 8 mb
GC occurs 6 times
allocate number 12 objet 
heap use 9 mb
GC occurs 7 times
root@server:~/ConsoleApp3#
```

The program exit when it allocated memory exceeds 9mb.While GC occurs 7 times.It seems that GC doesn't work at all.

The result with .NET Core 3.0

```
GC WorkStationGC
allocate number 1 objet 
heap use 1 mb
GC occurs 0 times
allocate number 2 objet 
heap use 2 mb
GC occurs 0 times
allocate number 3 objet 
heap use 3 mb
GC occurs 0 times
allocate number 4 objet 
heap use 1 mb
GC occurs 1 times
allocate number 5 objet 
heap use 2 mb
GC occurs 1 times
allocate number 6 objet 
heap use 3 mb
GC occurs 1 times
allocate number 7 objet 
heap use 1 mb
GC occurs 2 times
allocate number 8 objet 
heap use 2 mb
GC occurs 2 times
allocate number 9 objet 
heap use 3 mb
GC occurs 2 times
allocate number 10 objet 
heap use 1 mb
GC occurs 3 times
allocate number 11 objet 
heap use 2 mb
GC occurs 3 times
allocate number 12 objet 
heap use 3 mb
GC occurs 3 times
allocate number 13 objet 
heap use 1 mb
GC occurs 4 times
allocate number 14 objet 
heap use 2 mb
GC occurs 4 times
allocate number 15 objet 
heap use 3 mb
GC occurs 4 times
allocate number 16 objet 
heap use 1 mb
GC occurs 5 times
allocate number 17 objet 
heap use 2 mb
....
```

The program runs fine.

Comment: by the way, the latest version is preview6 that released 2 days back. may not help with this answer but just fyi

Comment: I have a guess can explain this problem.But I don't know if it is true. The object larger than 85kb will be allocated in LOH(large object heap). The GC will not collect them in LOH unless it has little memory in LOH.Because of the limitation of .net core3.0 , LOH can only get a smaller segment memory which is less than 9mb.While .net core2.2 has no limitation, so it allocated object until it exceed docker's limitation.